# Правый клик мышью в текстовом поле

Tags: java, swing

Почему в моем приложении ничего не происходит при правом клике мышью в текстовом поле (`JTextField`)? Нужно вешать свой слушатель? Если да, можно где-то пример посмотреть?
Хотелось бы, что бы правый клик вызывал стандартное всплывающие меню (копировать, вставить и т.д.).

Comment: вы бы код запостили...

Comment: на любое действие надо вешать слушатель...

Comment: Код слишком большой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

да не надо кода, просто, если у тебя там нету, или ты не знаешь как делать(посмотри примеры), надо:

1. повесить клик-листенер на твое поле,
2. при клике проверять или это правая кнопка мыши,
3. в обработчике событий описать действия, предположу, по выводу поп-ап меню для редактирования

Comment: Это даже для "Копировать - Вставить" нужно?

Comment: да, ты же архитектор и разработчик своей программы, если не ошибаюсь, в программах работают сочетания клавиш кнтр+С, +М =)

Comment: Окей, я просто думал что копировать / вставить меню можно как то и проще сделать.

Answer (score 6):

Как-то так:

```
textField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
        //если нажата правая кнопка--тут выполнить действие ее нажатия
        //P.S. BUTTON1--Левая кнопка, BUTTON2--колесо мыши                      
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: плюсану за старания, я ленивый ))

Answer (score 2):

В swing нет стандартного такого меню. Его нужно лепить самому! Вот пример (скопипастил с [link text](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=309516)):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.undo.UndoManager;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.*;

public class DocumentUndoManager {

    private static DocumentUndoManager instanse;
    private UndoActionListener listener;
    private HashMap items = new HashMap();
    private EditPopup popup;

    private DocumentUndoManager() {

        listener = new UndoActionListener();
        popup = new EditPopup();
    }

    public static DocumentUndoManager getInstance() {
        if (instanse==null) {
            instanse = new DocumentUndoManager();
        }
        return instanse;
    }

    public void registerDocumentHolder(JTextComponent documentHolder) {
        //создаем новый менеджер изменений документа
        UndoManager undo = new UndoManager();
        //запоминаем его для данного текстового поля
        items.put(documentHolder, undo);
        //получаем модель документа такстового поля
        Document doc = documentHolder.getDocument();
        //добавляем слушатель изменений документа
        doc.addUndoableEditListener(undo);
        //добавляем слушатель нажатий клавиш (он будет обрабатывать ctrl+z)
        documentHolder.addKeyListener(listener);
        //добавляем слушатель нажатий кнопок мыши (он обработает нажатие правой кнопки)
        documentHolder.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                //если нажата правая кнопка мыши
                if (e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                //if (e.isPopupTrigger()) { // <-- в линуксе (Fedora Core 5, KDE 3.5.3) это не работает
                    //устанавливаем текстовый компонент для меню
                    popup.setDocumentHolder((JTextComponent) e.getSource());
                    //отображаем всплывающее меню
                    popup.show((JTextComponent)e.getSource(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * очищает историю изменений для текстовых компонент
     * @param documentHolders список компонент (из JTextComponent)
     */
    public void clearChangeHistory(List documentHolders) {
        for (Iterator iterator = documentHolders.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            JTextComponent textComponent = (JTextComponent) iterator.next();
            UndoManager manager = (UndoManager) items.get(textComponent);
            manager.discardAllEdits();
        }
    }

    class EditPopup extends JPopupMenu {

        private JMenuItem copy;
        private JMenuItem cut;
        private JMenuItem paste;
        private JMenuItem undo;
        private JTextComponent documentHolder = null;

        public EditPopup() {

            copy = new JMenuItem("Копировать");
            copy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (documentHolder!=null) {
                        documentHolder.copy();
                    }
                }
            });

            cut = new JMenuItem("Вырезать");
            cut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (documentHolder!=null) {
                        documentHolder.cut();
                    }
                }
            });

            paste = new JMenuItem("Вставить");
            paste.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (documentHolder!=null) {
                        documentHolder.paste();
                    }
                }
            });

            undo = new JMenuItem("Отмена");
            undo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (documentHolder!=null) {
                        UndoManager manager = (UndoManager) items.get(documentHolder);
                        if (manager.canUndo()) {
                            manager.undo();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            add(copy);
            add(cut);
            add(paste);
            addSeparator();
            add(undo);
        }

        public void setDocumentHolder(JTextComponent documentHolder) {
            this.documentHolder = documentHolder;
            //устанавливаем доступность пунктов "копировать" и "вырезать"
            if (documentHolder.getSelectedText()!= null && documentHolder.getSelectedText()!= null) {
                copy.setEnabled(true);
                cut.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else {
                copy.setEnabled(false);
                cut.setEnabled(false);
            }

            //устанавливаем доступность пункта "вставить"
            Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(this);
            DataFlavor flavor = DataFlavor.stringFlavor;
            if (contents!=null && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(flavor)) {
                paste.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else {
                paste.setEnabled(false);
            }

            //устанавливаем доступность пункта "отмена"
            UndoManager manager = (UndoManager) items.get(documentHolder);
            if (manager.canUndo()) {
                undo.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else {
                undo.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }

    }

    class UndoActionListener extends KeyAdapter {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z && e.isControlDown()) {
                UndoManager manager = (UndoManager) items.get(e.getSource());
                if (manager.canUndo()) {
                    manager.undo();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```